# Object.assign() with Omit type in TypeScript not working as expected

Tags: typescript, generics, functional-programming, typescript-generics

I'm trying to craft a fancy generic `mergeArray` function which can merge object arrays of type `T` and `U` on a certain shared key `matchKey`. Note also that `U extends T`. I'm quite close, but apparently I misunderstand either the `Object.assign` typings or how `Omit` works. Here's what I have so far:

```js
export const mergeArray = <T, U extends T>(params: {
  mergeInArray: Array<T>
  existingArray: Array<U>
  matchKey: keyof T
  fallbackValues: Omit<U, keyof T>
}): Array<U> => {
  const {
    mergeInArray,
    existingArray,
    matchKey,
    fallbackValues,
  } = params
  return mergeInArray.map(itemToMergeIn => {
    const existingItem = existingArray.find(
      searchItem => searchItem[matchKey] === itemToMergeIn[matchKey]
    )
    if (existingItem) {
        return Object.assign(existingItem, itemToMergeIn)
    }
    return Object.assign(fallbackValues, itemToMergeIn) // <-- TypeScript doesn't like this line :(
  })
}
```

The error comes with the last line of the function:

```
Type '(Omit<U, keyof T> & T)[]' is not assignable to type 'U[]'.
  Type 'Omit<U, keyof T> & T' is not assignable to type 'U'.
    'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Omit<U, keyof T> & T'.ts(2322)
```

I don't understand; how can a union of types `T` and `Omit<U, keyof T>` be by definition anything other than `U`, because `U extends T`!

If I put `as U` at the end of that last line, my function passes the type check. But this should not be required - is it possible to get my function to pass type checking without this `as`?

Comment: What if `T` was `{x: {a: string}}` and `U` was `{x: {a: string; b: number}}`? `U` still extends `T`, but `Omit<U, keyof T> & T` would be just `{x: {a: string}}`, which is not assignable to `U` due to the missing `b`. This is actually the case for `Object.assign(existingItem, itemToMergeIn)` as well, just that [the typings for `Object.assign` aren't precisely correct](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727); `Object.assign(existingItem, itemToMergeIn)` is typed to return `T & U`, whereas it should really be something like `Omit<U, keyof T> & T`.